# Vue - Mixin on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I navigate using vue router, everything works. Ex: I click on button using @click=login(). Above the login method

```
methods: {
    login () {
      this.$router.push('/admin')
    }
```

So vue redirect user to '/Admin' page and the router calls beforeEach event where I check if the page has meta attribute to validate user access

Then on my router/index.js

```
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    Routes
  ]
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAdminAuth) {
    let app = router.app.$data || {isAuthenticated: false}
    if (app.isAuthenticated) {
      // already signed in, we can navigate anywhere
      next()
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdminAuth)) {
      // authentication is required. Trigger the sign in process, including the return URI
      console.log(router.app.hello)
      let authenticate = router.app.authenticate
      authenticate(to.path).then(() => {
        console.log('authenticating a protected url:' + to.path)
        next()
      })
    } else {
      // No auth required. We can navigate
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

To validade the user I'm usgin global method and this works. But when user navigate to '/Admin' from URL, not from my button, the global variable is undefined. So I tried to use Mixin, but the result was the same.

Here is my main.js where I specify global method and the mixin:

```
var myMixin = {
  methods: {
    hello: function () {
      console.log('Bem-vindo ao mixin!')
    }
  }
}

const globalData = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: '',
  mgr: mgr
}

const globalMethods = {
  async authenticate (returnPath) {
    const user = await this.$root.getUser()
    if (user) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true
      this.user = user
    } else {
      await this.$root.signIn(returnPath)
    }
  },
  async getUser () {
    try {
      let user = await this.mgr.getUser()
      console.log(user)
      return user
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },
  signIn (returnPath) {
    returnPath ? this.mgr.signinRedirect({ state: returnPath })
        : this.mgr.signinRedirect()
  }
}

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  mixins: [myMixin],
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  data: globalData,
  methods: globalMethods
})
```

How can I do that? Execute a defined method when user navigate by URL?

Comment: You could move it into the component's `beforeCreate` hook.

Comment: Can you please give me an exemple? I cant undestande. Do you mean move the router.beforeEach logic to the beforeCreate hook of router?